# finally in useMutatation in react query

Tags: reactjs, react-query

This is my loading state,

```
const [loading,setLoading] = useState(true)
```

Usually in axios promise I'm setting the loading state to `false` in `finally()`,

```
axios.post(...).then().catch().finally(() => setLoading(false));
```

**How to do this one in react query?**

```
const {data,isLoading} = useMutation(...);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass `onSettled` option to `useMutation`. Or you can also use `onSuccess` and `onError` options.

```
useMutation(your_function, {
  onError: (error, variables, context) => {
     // An error happened!
  },
  onSuccess: (data, variables, context) => {
    // Success
  },
  onSettled: async () => {
    console.log("called always")
  },
})
```

docs: https://react-query-v3.tanstack.com/guides/mutations

Comment: So on settled called at the end?

Comment: yes. whether it is error or success on settled will be called